# Preserving type information in an Oracle view when using functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, types, oracle12c, sql-view

I have a view like this one:

```
SELECT NVL(foo, 0) foo FROM bar
```

Unfortunately, this view looses the fact that `bar.foo` is `NUMBER(1)` and instead just assign it as `NUMBER`. I want to keep the type information, so I did this:

```
SELECT CAST(NVL(foo, 0) AS NUMBER(1)) foo FROM bar
```

This works, but if I have a lot of columns like `foo` I need to duplicate the type information. Would I change the precision of one of them, I would have to change it in the view as well or risk loosing precision. So ideally I would want to do something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(NVL(foo, 0) AS TYPE(foo)) foo FROM bar
```

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as you would implicitly change the view definition when changing the base table.

You might want to avoid inserting `NULL` data at all: If your business logic allows restricting your columns to `NOT NULL`, you can either implement the `NLV(foo,0)` logic on client side or use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to convert all `NULL` inserts to `0`:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  foo NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
  );

CREATE TRIGGER TRG1 BEFORE INSERT ON T1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.foo := NVL(:old.foo, 0);
END;
/
```

Then you can

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (NULL);

SELECT * FROM T1;
```

which will give you `0`

See [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm%20Oracle%20Documentation%20on%20CREATE%20TRIGGER)